# Backup database at certain intervals?

Tags: windows, asp.net, sql, sql-server

My client would like to have the database backed up several times per day, as well as the ability to backup the database manually.

I've created a page to backup the database manually, it just calls a stored procedure that backs up the database.

But I'm having trouble with having the database backup at certain intervals, say noon and midnight. I thought about setting up the server to hit my manual backup page at certain intervals, but I didn't know if SQL Server has something built in that would do backups at specific times.

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: they don't have a DBA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SQL Server Agent to schedule the stored procedure that you call to make the backups.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx